# Sync app on simulator from VS Code is very slow

Tags: macos, performance, flutter, visual-studio-code, ios-simulator

I'm writing an App (1st time) with Flutter on MacOS from VS Code.

All works but when I run the app it is very slow with the synchronization, I mean that if I change something in the home screen, save then click "run on iOS device" it loads the old version, ignoring my edits but after a random time it loads the right version with the correct edits.

I'm working on Catalina 10.15.4 (macbook pro 13 inch early 2015, Xcode updated to the latest version).

This is the code wrote in the home screen, other files are unchanged from the original template.
(I added 3 Images to the LaunchScreen and an other for the Android splash screen).

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('BuddyLang'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FlatButton(
          onPressed: (){},
          child: Text('click me'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `Flutter clean` and then `Restart` your app and also check this happen is `Flutter run --release`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried to restart flutter but it doesn't change, it's the same. With "Flutter run --release" it says "No supported devices connected."

Comment: And when I press "r" to restart flutter the output is "flutter restart" then "Could not find a command named restart". :|